# How to build a navbar under bootstrap framework with multi level push menu on mobile view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently, I working on web layout update, the objective of this update is to change the current dropdown menu to multilevel push menu. I have been searching the plugin from online.Unfortunately, the available plugins get from online are not compatible with the bootstrap 3. To achieve the requirement, I would like to get the tutorial about how to build this menu or any plugin can share it with me here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one? Simple but it works, than you can modify by your style : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Off-canvas-Bootstrap-Navigation/#

Comment: this one is dropdown menu, I looking on multilevel push menu

Comment: This is the [example](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples.html) of I looking for the mobile view